# How to update a column value in Cassandra Using CQL?

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I have created a keyspace with two column fields. One is Id and another one is name. I have inserted records in that keyspace. I want to update the name filed of a particular id.

I have used the following CQL query

```
UPDATE keyspaceName/columnFalmilyName SET name='name' WHERE id = 'id'
```

While Executing this query it throws the Exception of

```
InvalidRequestException(why:line 1:56 mismatched input 'id' expecting K_KEY)...
```

If the query framed is wrong means, how to update the record using CQL?

Comment: Keep in mind that CQL is a lot more restricted than SQL. Not really sure about your issue, but the error message suggests that 'id' is not a key or a key alias (see [1](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html#update)). 
As id is a column rather than (part of) a row key, I'd guess that this operation is simply not possible with Cassandra.

Comment: Can you post your CF definition?

Answer (score 0):

Inserts and updates require specifying the row key, whereas you seem to be trying to use a column name. What key have you used when inserting new id,name pairs?

Refer to the CQL documentation on [http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html][1]

```
<update-stmt> ::= UPDATE <tablename>
                  ( USING <option> ( AND <option> )* )?
                  SET <assignment> ( ',' <assignment> )*
                  WHERE <where-clause>
The UPDATE statement writes one or more columns for a given row in a table. The 
<where-clause> is used to select the row to update and must include all columns 
composing the PRIMARY KEY. Other columns values are specified through <assignment> 
after the SET keyword.
```

You need to take a look at your ColumnFamily definition and see what your primary key is.

Comment: It would've been useful if you provided an example instead of a formular

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
UPDATE keyspaceName/columnFalmilyName SET name='name' WHERE id =  (without '')